# How do I memoize this program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

[PepCoding | Count Binary Strings](https://www.pepcoding.com/resources/online-java-foundation/dynamic-programming-and-greedy/count-binary-strings-official/ojquestion).

> 1. You are given a number n.
> 2. You are required to print the number of binary strings of length n with no consecutive 0's.

My code:

```cpp
void solve(int n ,string ans  , vector<string> &myAns){
  if(ans.size()==n) {
    //cout << ans << "\n";
    myAns.push_back(ans);
    return;
  }
  if(ans.back() == '0'){
    solve(n , ans + "1" , myAns);
  }
  else{
    solve(n , ans + "0" , myAns);
    solve(n , ans + "1" , myAns);
  }
}
```

How should I store the recurring strings, in a hash or something?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a description of your problem. Questions are expected to be self-contained and not rely on external links for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are required to print the **number** of binary strings of length n with no consecutive 0's, not to actually form (and store or print) all of them.

So, yes, a recursive solution could greatly benefit from memoization, but not of all the single strings. What you should store is the *number* of strings for each length. *Two* numbers, actually, one of the strings preceded by a `1` and one of those preceded by a `0`.

```
long long solve(long long n, bool is_previous_a_zero = false)
{
    // Memoize the number of strings for each length and 
    // possible previous character.
    using key_t = std::pair<long long, bool>;
    static std::map<key_t, long long> mem{
        {{1, false}, 2},    // "0", "1"
        {{1, true}, 1}      // "1" after a "****0"
    };

    if ( n < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    // First check if the result is already memoized.
    key_t key{ n, is_previous_a_zero };
    auto const candidate = mem.lower_bound(key);
    if( candidate != mem.cend()  and  candidate->first == key ) {
        return candidate->second;
    }

    // Otherwise evaluate it recursively and store it, before returning.
    long long result = is_previous_a_zero
                     ? solve(n - 1, false)
                     : solve(n - 1, true) + solve(n - 1, false);

    mem.emplace_hint(candidate, key, result);

    return result;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/x8ePfjdch) this approach is tested for all the lengths up to 45.

Note that if you are interested only in runtime efficiency you can just precalculate all those numbers at compile time.

```
template< std::size_t N >
constexpr auto make_lut()
{
    std::array<long long, N + 1> lut{0, 2, 3};
    for ( size_t i = 3; i <= N; ++i) {
        lut[i] = lut[i - 1] + lut[i - 2];  // Yeah, it's a Fibonacci sequence.
    }
    return lut;
}

// Then it can be called like so
constexpr auto lut{ make_lut<45>() };

// The number of binary strings of length n with no consecutive 0's = lut[n];
```

You can test it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/os6P85qdv).

To prove that the last snippet really solves the posted problem, consider theese points:

- There are only 2 possible binary strings of length 1: `"0"` and `"1"`.
- There are 3 possible binary strings of length 2 with no consecutive 0's: `"01"`, `"10"` and `"11"`.
- All the possible strings of length `n` are all the strings composed prepending a `"1"` to all the strings of length `n - 1`, plus all the strings composed prepending `"01"` to all the strings of length `n - 2`. Any other combination would result in consecutive zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you don't need dynamic programming or recursion for this algo. You can simply use the below one (please note that this is a first sketch there might exist a more efficient solution):

```cpp
  size_t currentLength = 1;
  results_.push_back("0");
  results_.push_back("1");

  while(currentLength < length_)
  {
    size_t size = results_.size();  
    for(size_t i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
      string& elem = results_[i];
      if(elem.back() == '0')
      {
          elem.push_back('1');
      }
      else
      {
          results_.push_back(elem + "0");
          elem.push_back('1');
      }
    }
    currentLength = results_.back().size();
  }
```

If you still want to memoize, you need to create a cache which is an std::map or an std::unordered_map in its simplest form. Usually what you can do is create a unique key from the inputs and save the return value.

Comment: Back when I was a kid we didn't even have dynamic programming. We just had programming. And we liked it that way. We coded uphill, both ways, for 40 miles through 20 feet of snow.

Comment: All our programming was static, and we liked it that way :)